# MPEG DASH - do I need to have audio and video tracks as seperate source file for creating DASH package using mp4box

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, mpeg-dash

I have one source mp4, I  tried to create MPEG DASH package using mp4box by GPAC.
I am able to play output MPD files in OSMO4 player by GPAC.

However I am not able to play the same in DASH JS player @ http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/0.2.3/index.html

When I try to play the mpd in it I get error "Error creating source buffer"

I tried reading their MPD files, and I found that those guys are using audio and video as separate source track.

Ques1) Does DASH specs states that audio and video tracks should be seprate source tracks?

Ques2) Please find below the MPD file created by me, Let me know if anybody thinks that there is a problem in it

```
<MPD type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011"    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H2M31.63S">
<ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
<Title>Media Presentation Description for file flight_3000.mp4 generated with GPAC </Title>
</ProgramInformation>
 <Period start="PT0S" duration="PT0H2M31.63S">
  <AdaptationSet>
<ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video"/>
<ContentComponent id="2" contentType="audio" lang="und"/>
<SegmentTemplate initialization="flight_init.mp4"/>
<Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.02" width="1280" height="720" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="und" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="3096320">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="20164" media="flight_test_flight_3000$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
<Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.02" width="640" height="360" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="und" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="1119428">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="20099" media="flight_test_flight_1000$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
<Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640014,mp4a.40.02" width="320" height="180" sampleRate="44100" numChannels="2" lang="und" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="722208">
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="20164" media="flight_test_flight_600$Number$.mp4" startNumber="1"/>
</Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period> 
</MPD>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Does DASH specs states that audio and video tracks should be separate source tracks?

Mpeg-Dash specs are not restrictive about this: you can either have both video and audio multiplexed in the same segment, or you can separate them in two files. 
Both options are possible with mp4box, you just have to separate them with ffmpeg before dashifying them with mp4box.

> Please find below the MPD file created by me, Let me know if anybody thinks that there is a problem in it

Your mpd seems ok. The DASH-IF player officially supports only onDemand and Live profiles for now, so maybe you should try to change the -profile option of MP4BOX from full to onDemand.
More info is available at their Github Wiki : https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki

Answer (score 0):

The DASH-IF player targets the DASH-264 spec and this recommends using demultiplexed streams (separate audio and video tracks). You may find however that your mpd plays in IE11 but fails  in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to use MP4Box, you can give the free version of [www.bitcodin.com](http://www.bitcodin.com/) a try. I was able to create DASH content which can be played with dash.js